# The type or namespace name 'Firebase' could not be found when cloning from github

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I've added Firebase auth to my unity project and everything is working fine, I can build it and test it, and it works. But when I push to github and clone it elsewhere, the following errors occur:

```
The type or namespace name 'Firebase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'FirebaseAuth' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I've checked and the package for Firebase is not installed in the project but the plugin is there, when I re-import the package, it says all the files being imported are new.
The .gitignore of the repository is as follows:

```
# This .gitignore file should be placed at the root of your Unity project directory
#
# Get latest from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore
#
/[Ll]ibrary/
/[Tt]emp/
/[Oo]bj/
/[Bb]uild/
/[Bb]uilds/
/[Ll]ogs/
/[Mm]emoryCaptures/

# Asset meta data should only be ignored when the corresponding asset is also ignored
!/[Aa]ssets/**/*.meta

# Exception for Firebase files
!/[Aa]ssets/Plugins/Android/

# Uncomment this line if you wish to ignore the asset store tools plugin
# /[Aa]ssets/AssetStoreTools*

# Autogenerated Jetbrains Rider plugin
[Aa]ssets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*

# TextMesh Pro files
[Aa]ssets/TextMesh*Pro/

# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/

# Gradle cache directory
.gradle/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
*.mdb
*.opendb
*.VC.db

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.pdb.meta
*.mdb.meta

# Unity3D generated file on crash reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.unitypackage

# Crashlytics generated file
crashlytics-build.properties

# StyleCop cache
StyleCop.Cache
Packages/packages-lock.json
Packages/manifest.json

# FMOD files
[Aa]ssets/Plugins/FMOD/Cache/Editor.meta
[Aa]ssets/Plugins/FMOD/Resources/FMODStudioCache.asset
[Aa]ssets/Plugins/FMOD/.cache
[Aa]ssets/Plugins/FMOD/.user
[Aa]ssets/Plugins/FMOD/.unsaved
[Aa]ssets/Plugins/FMOD/Cache/Editor/FMODStudioCache.asset
[Aa]ssets/Plugins/FMOD/Cache/Editor/FMODStudioCache.asset.meta
[Ff]mod_editor.log
```

How can I commit the project, in a way it works, to the repository?

Comment: This does sound like a .gitignore issue. I haven't seen the `!` syntax before, but maybe the line ignoring meta files is an issue? Also, if you did migrate stuff to the package manager, the lines ignoring Packages/ would be an issue (generally those should be safe to include).

Comment: Those are the ones that were making it not work, removing them or, well, uploading them to github using the browser made the project function again. Thank you very much!